# Resizing virtualbox vdi doesn't work

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, vdi

I tried resizing my VirtualBox disk (.vdi) with VBoxManage, but it didn't resize the hard drive.  The command while in the root folder of VirtualBox was:

`VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\<name>\VirtualBox Vms\Linux Mint 14.1\Linux Mint 14.vdi" --resize 30000`.

The output showed 0%...20%....40%...100% looking like it was successful.  Now my .vdi in VirtualBox shows the virtual size as being 29.30gb, but the actual size is still 7.90gb.  When I boot into Linux Mint, it still notifies me that the hard drive is out of space.

Answer (score 3):

Your hard drive is bigger, but you still have your old small partition on it. Use some partitioning software (for example GParted) to resize the partition.

Comment: I booted into GParted, but wasn't able to increase the partition's storage - only decrease the size.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Any solutions to this?

Comment: I had the same issue, turns out it's because i had snapshots.. Delete all your snapshots then try resizing, it will work instantly.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=46979) on virtualbox's own web page, this will not work if you have snapshots in your configuration.

Unfortunantly the only known solution to this is to merge all the snapshots into base and then do the resize afterwards on the base .vdi file.

And then you have to use tools in linux to expand your partition(s) over the newly emerged hard disk space. GParted or other linux expanding tools should do the job here.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. What you see is the actual size which reflect the overall size of your virtual OS but the number changes as you keep adding more stuff to the storage. And as actual size gets bigger and bigger reaching to the virtual size, you will get running out of space warning.