# Vbox guest does not see new size of resized disk

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning

I resized a VDI disk to 30 GB (while Vbox and guest were shutdown):

```
VBoxmanage modifyhd MyLinux.vdi --resize 30000
```

Vbox now shows the new size in the GUI.
But the guest does not see the resized disk.
When using `fdisk -l` the old size is displayed. Same goes for every other command I tried.

Host is Win10, Guest ist Fedora25

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this does not work when snapshots are used (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/554445/resizing-virtualbox-vdi-doesnt-work?rq=1)).

To solve this problem I created a clone of the VM from a snapshot.
This new VM then shows the correct disk size in Vbox and the guest.